# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'gall'

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.6 and I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/SpatialTemp/model/test_st_market.py", line 163, in <module>
    gallery_label, gallery_frames = get_id(gallery_path)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/SpatialTemp/model/test_st_market.py", line 155, in get_id
    labels.append(int(label))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'gall'
```

Code is as follows

```py
def get_id(img_path):
    labels = []
    frames = []
    for path, v in img_path:
        filename = path.split('/')[-1]
        label = filename[0:4]
        frame = filename[9:16]
        frame = filename.split('_')[2][1:]
        if label[0:2]=='-1':
            labels.append(-1)
        else:
            labels.append(int(label))
            frames.append(int(frame))
        return labels, frames
```

Comment: The first four characters in the pathname aren't a number, and they won't convert

Comment: Note that there is twice `frame = ...` one after another (lines 7 & 8) and in this context seems to be an oversight.

Comment: To improve your question, provide examples of input and expected output of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code takes a path and parse the first 4 chars as a label, then it tries to convert it to int (probably you expect it to be a number).

The error means that this label (the first 4 chars in your file name) is 'gall', which can`t be converted to int....